# Vim Keymap with Multiplicity on VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, multiplicity

I have remapped some vim keys in VS Code (using Vim emulation) but I can't manage to use them with multiplicity.

What this means is that when you normally press 3dd it deletes 3 lines. I have keymapped the normal version of the function dd like this

```
    {
        "before": ["<Leader>","c","l"],
        "after": ["d","d"]
    }
```

but it doesn't work if I press 3-leader-c-l.

How do you keymap keys with that functionality?

Comment: so if you press `3dd` it is working? and does it work when you leave out the `<leader>` key and have a look if it works?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo If I press 3dd it works normally. If I don't press the leader key it is not supposed to work either way.

Comment: I mean removing the leader key from the mapping. Just map `cl` to `dd` and see if it works, the problem may be in the leader-key handling of vs-code. But it is just a guess